# What are the advantages of Chrome Web Store?

Tags: chrome-web-store

Is [Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore) going to be just another web directory managed by Google for their own purposes? What would be the benefit to a regular user of web applications if and if not using the Chrome browser? What unique features is it going to have?

This is subjective, I just want to hear other opinions about it.

Comment: A platform for new developers to show off their stuff? Having your app hosted on a solid cloud service?

Comment: And why wouldn't you submit that as an answer? Also, I'm not sure about the cloud service. I think they can all be hosted anywhere, Chrome Web Store just aggregates them.

Comment: If you're interested in the WebStore then there is a proposal for a new stack site geared towards Chrome Extensions and the WebStore.

http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/10910/google-chrome-extensions-webstore

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Chrome Web Store is really just an App aggregator for apps that use newer technologies like HTML5 which allows Google to "Install" the web apps into your browser.

All that really means is Google is creating a place where you can buy or download apps that are trusted and have been checked.  And if you access them via the Chrome web browser you will probably get some neat extra integration that makes at least some of the web apps a little more useful.

Answer (score 0):

Like RandomBen has already mentioned, Google want the WebStore to be the "go to" place for users to download and install web apps to their browser.

I also believe that you wont be as restricted to the technologies you can use in WebStore apps, unlike Chrome Extensions where it's HTML, CSS and JavaScript only.

Comment: I would recommend to put the last paragraph into a comment under your own answer. The proposal might get outdated in a couple of months

Answer (score 0):

An example integration is their background feature:

http://blog.chromium.org/2011/02/amping-up-chromes-background-feature.html

"Apps and extensions that use the new “background” feature can continue to run in the background—even if the user closes down all of Chrome’s windows. “Background apps” will continue to run until Chrome exits. The next time Chrome starts up, any background windows that were previously running will also be re-launched. These windows are not going to be visible but they will be able to perform tasks like checking for server-side changes and pre-emptively loading content into local storage."